# Manage conflicts with svn update command line

Tags: command-line, batch-file, svn, tortoise-svn

I'm implementing a batch program that updates recursively some SVN projects in a directory. I work with Tortoise SVN.

All works fine expect one case: when I have conflicts during the update, the command line stops and prompts this message:

```
Conflict discovered in 'XXXXXXX.XX'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options: p
```

I would like to know if it's possible by a command parameter to "force" the "p" choice everytime without stopping my command.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Try following command:

```
svn update --accept postpone
```

Alternatively try this command:

```
svn update --non-interactive
```

Comment: Problem with "svn update --non-interactive" is that it finishes executing if a choice should be made. This is probably what you don't want.

Comment: The first one works great!